# android: "Flashing" RectF by rapidly show/hide with timer

Tags: android, timer, rect

I am trying to rapidly show and hide a rectangle with RectF with a timer.
Here's my code for RectF:

```
mRectPath.addRect(_rectMatrix.get(i),Path.Direction.CW);
```

I want to set a timer, and show/hide the RectF.
Basically, show the RectF for 0.01 sec, hide it for 0.01 sec, show for 0.01 sec, etc.

How would I implement such a rapidly showing and hiding functionality for RectF?
Could you please show me some sample code?
Thanks,

Comment: You want your rectangle's visibility to toggle at 100Hz? Do you expect that to be perceptible to the human eye?

Comment: Hi Mike, I can change that parameter. I just need to know the functionality, please. Hope you can help?